# How to insert multiple rows in postgresql using CTE (WITH)

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I am trying to write a function that receive an array of ids (`posts`),
and insert all of them to another table (`offer`).
I need the ids from the newly created rows (`offers`) for more processing later.

I'm getting an error using `WITH`

```
create function foo (post_ids text[])
returns text[]
as $$
  with
  offer_ids as (insert into app.offer (user_email, post_id)
                  values ('a@a.com', unnest(foo.post_ids))
                  returning id),
  ...
  select array_agg(id) from offer_ids;
$$ language sql security definer;
```

Error

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

How can I return multiple rows from a `WITH` and use it later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the error comes from the CTE part, but from the INSERT part. Set returning functions like `unnest` have to be used as part of a SELECT statement:

```
with offer_ids as (
     insert into app.offer (user_email, post_id)
     select 'a@a.com', f.pid
     from unnest(foo.post_ids) as f(pid)
     returning id
),
...
select array_agg(id) 
from offer_ids;
```